# Bundle.main.url(forResource: "hello", withExtension: "html") is returning nil

Tags: ios, swift

I have created hello.html file .when I am try to access it,url is returning nil everytime.

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "hello", withExtension: "html"){
            if let htmlData = try? Data(contentsOf:url){
                let baseURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.bundlePath)
                webView.load(htmlData, mimeType: "text/html", textEncodingName: "UTF-8", baseURL: baseURL)

            }
        }

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
```

Comment: Your HTML file isn't added to your target.

Comment: got it thanks man:)

Answer (score 2):

[image]

1. drop hello.html in your project
2. click Copy items if needed
3. add to targets project
4. it's ok

Comment: But the html file is already in the project. This answer is only useful when adding new files to the project.

Comment: If you html file in sanbox,use `FileManager` get file path,then webview loading,it's ok